# .net core assembly can not concurrently run on linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux

I wrote an dotnet core app for running on linux.
published a single executable file with self-contained enabled.

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64 -o ${dst_path} -v n /p:PublishTrimmed=true /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

But strangely it can only run a single instance.
Because when it's running, it will remove the execute permission of the file.

```
$ ./Test
10/21/2020 11:50:27 AM [Info] Server started at ws://0.0.0.0:12500 (actual port 12500)
$ ls -l Test  <---------Test is running, ls -l is executed in another terminal
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 53081298 10月 21 11:50 Test
```

And execute permission is added back after the runnning process exited.

```
$ ls -l Test  <------------Test is not running.
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53081298 10月 21 11:50 Test
```

So I can not start more than one process.

I am really confused with this problem.
Could anyone help?

Comment: This issue is not the same, but  seems somewhat similar: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4644.  It is fixed in  .net core 3.1.4.  What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering, I found the root reason.

Just in case other may encount the same stupid situation,  leave a message here.

My problem is caused by virutalBox.
Because I put my published assembly **Test** in the shared directory of my host between shared virtual machine.

After move my file **Test** to virtual machine's home directory, it works well.

And thank you for your help @jdoer1997